# removing class from a div in c#

Tags: c#, css

I tried using the server-side `.CssClass`, but this isn't available for me to use.
My div has `runat="server"` so I can access it, but I just cannot see `.CssClass` in the drop-down when i hit ".". Does anyone know how to get past this or any other solution that might work?

Ok, my bad. I just found out that this does not work for HTML controls, only for asp controls

Comment: Showing some of your source code might help.

Comment: You can use an ASP:Panel rather than a div marked as server side if you want to access .CssClass.  If you don't, see answer for the method you need to use to alter it.

Comment: @blesh code added for reference

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are wanting to read the class name, you will need to use the code:

```
string className = Test.Attributes["class"].ToString();
```

If you are wanting to replace a specific class you will need to use the code:

```
Test.Attributes.Add("class", Test.Attributes["class"].ToString().Replace("spacerDiv", ""));
```

Comment: the code above will work well if we have only once class, however it may mess up the class in case we have multiple class which contains spacerDiv.

Answer (score 7):

```
HTML
<div id="Test" runat="server"></div>
```

Code Behind

```
add =>       Test.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass")

remove =>    Test.Attributes.("class") = "";
```

Comment: I want to remove a class that the div already has, Attributes.Add will not help there.

Comment: please read the question. I mentioned that I cannot access .CssClass

Comment: @neuDev33: try this **Test.Attributes.Add("class", "")**

Comment: that doesn't work either, as it does not remove the earlier class already added, it will just add another "" class.

Answer (score 2):

This would be more specific:

HTML

```
<div id="Test" runat="server"></div>
```

Server code:

```
Test.Attributes.Remove("class");
```

Comment: This would remove all classes, not just the one OP wants to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same solution as Tim, but I removed the not needed toString method.

```
myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", myDiv.Attributes["class"].Replace("spacerDiv", ""));
```

To add a class to a div is somewhat the same.

```
myDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "spacerDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to handle adding or removing class for any HtmlGenericControl would be to use the extension as provided below:

```
  public static void RemoveCssClass(this HtmlGenericControl controlInstance, string css)
    {
        var strCssClass = controlInstance.Attributes["class"];
        controlInstance.Attributes["class"] = string.Join(" ", strCssClass.Split(' ').Where(x => x != css).ToArray());
    }

    public static void AddCssClass(this HtmlGenericControl controlInstance, string css)
    {
        var strCssClass = controlInstance.Attributes["class"];
        controlInstance.Attributes["class"] = string.Join($" {css} ", strCssClass.Split(' ').ToArray());
    }
```

For WebControl the same code can be modified as below:

```
public static void RemoveCssClass(this WebControl controlInstance, string css)
        {
            controlInstance.CssClass = string.Join(" ", controlInstance.CssClass.Split(' ').Where(x => x != css).ToArray());
        }

    public static void AddCssClass(this WebControl controlInstance, string css)
    {
        controlInstance.CssClass = string.Join($" {css} ", controlInstance.CssClass.Split(' ').ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: For your add methods you need to add an if check to the css class. The issue is the Split() method returns an empty string and the join will not join properly if no class is set on your control.

Comment: I tried it with empty class as well. The join worked as expected. It give me single class.

Answer (score -1):

**Remove css class**

myDiv.Attributes["class"]=" ";

Comment: And what will happen?

Comment: all css class will be removed.
if you need any css class just write the class name inside the double code.
Example:
myDiv.Attributes["class"]="col-sm-6"